# how to assign a shape to an edge?

Tags: image-processing

I have an image with only black and white pixels. The image contains edges (the black pixels) with the width of one pixel (each black pixel has exactly one or two black neighbourpixels). Now i want to group the edges into different shape classes (e.g. line, triangle, ellipse). Problem: the edges are not perfect lines, triangles or ellipses.

I think i can partially solve the problem by logical thinking. But i also have more complex geometries where this will be more difficult.

Does anyone know how to solve this kind of problem? Or can anyone give me some ideas?

Answer (score 0):

A general way to find the shape of the edges will be to find the convex hull of the points. After that you can try to discard sides in the convex hull which are small than a certain threshold.

Comment: Thank you for this useful information. Thats a good solution for the simple geometries. But what about more complex geometries which opencv cannot know? Also, i would like to write the code by myself and avoid using opencv. I am interested in theory to this problem.

Comment: I think each shape has a different way to find the best fit. For fitting circle you can use a least squares. For fitting a ellipse or rectangle you can use the eign decomposition of the correlation matrix of the shape coordinates. For a general method maybe find the convexhull of the shape and than discard edges that are very small or something like that.

Comment: Thank you for mentioning convexhull! That will help me alot to fullfill my goals! How can i upvote you, and mark the anwser as anwsered?